# accessing all the Labels inside Table at once in css

Tags: css, asp.net

I was wondering we we could style all label which are inside table at once without using class.

```
 <table class="tbl_plbl">
                <tr>
                    <td><b> UserName: </b> </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'/></td> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><b> RealName: </b> </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'/></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b> Email: </b> </td>
                     <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email")%>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b> Address: </b> </td>
                     <td><asp:Label  ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address")%>' /></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td><b> Sex: </b> </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sex")%>' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b> Account: </b> </td>
                    <td> <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("acType")%>'/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
```

Since its possible to access the tr of table as

```
.tbl_plbl tr
{
height:30px;
width:150px;    
}
```

I thought it is possible to access all the label as well.I tried this but didnt work

```
.tbl_plbl td Label
{
background-color:Blue;    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.net `Label`s are rendered as a HTML `span`, so you would have to:

```
.tbl_plbl td span {
    background-color: blue;    
}
```

Since there might be more `span`s in your cells than just the ones rendered by `Label` elements, you probably want to assign a class name to distinguish between the label and the not-label ones.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" CssClass='label' Text='...'/>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
.tbl_plbl td span.label {
    background-color: blue;    
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why `height and width` are not working inside `tbl_plbl td span` class

Comment: @user35 `span`s are inline elements. For height and width to work, you would have to convert them to block level elements, for example by specifing `display: inline-block` in your CSS

Comment: so i have to use `cssclass` anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
  .tbl_plbl
        {
        }
        .tbl_tr
        {
            height: 30px;
            width: 150px;
        }
        .tbl_td
        {
            background-color: Blue;
            color :White; 
        }




<table class="tbl_plbl">
        <tr class="tbl_tr">
            <td>
                <b>UserName: </b>
            </td>
            <td class="tbl_td">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>RealName: </b>
            </td>
            <td class="tbl_td">
                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Email: </b>
            </td>
            <td class="tbl_td">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Address: </b>
            </td>
            <td class="tbl_td">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Sex: </b>
            </td>
            <td class="tbl_td">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sex")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Account: </b>
            </td>
            <td class="tbl_td">
                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("acType")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I was asking if its possible without using class

Comment: you can add individually in particular label

Comment: I was trying to simply so no individually..would increase more work to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following

```
table.tbl_plbl td span
{
  background-color:blue;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
table label
{
  background-color:Blue;  
}
```